# Laravel 5.8 email verification - But forced the user to be logged

Tags: laravel

I am new to Laravel and I have come across an issue and I hope you can help me with it.
I have enabled email verification in laravel so that the new users are forwarded to the standard verify email page and then receive a verify email.
The problem is, as soon as the user is referred to the email verify notification page the user is already logged in! I want to make sure that the user is NOT logged in referred to this page.
Do you know how I can solve that.

thanks in advance

Comment: Hi! Can you provide code of what you have tried so far?

Comment: I started a new project and only entered the basic codes.
I have not entered any special codes.

Comment: I think it's Laravel verification page strategy. Try maybe to change the auth function to your specific function without a logged redirect page.

Comment: it is indeed laravel verification strategy. I have been busy solving this issue for 2 days but I can't find the solution! How to override the auth function!!

Comment: Yes, this is how laravel verification works, you can protect routes with the 'verified' middleware, this will redirect the user to the verification page.
https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/verification#verification-routing

Answer (score 0):

You could make a middleware to verify all requests that are logged in and have their emails verified. And then group the routes you want to be hidden from unverified users and give that group the email middleware you've just made.